# Why is my classifier not giving me binary results?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I created a linear ReLu network that is supposed to over-fit to my data. I use BCEWithLogisticLoss as the loss function. I was using it to classify 3d points. Since the data were small enough I didn't care to make into batches. And it worked fine. However now that I've implemented batches into it it seems that the predicted values aren't what I expect (i.e 0 or 1) instead it give me numbers like -25.4562 I didn't change anything else from the network only the batches.

I tried the binary loss function BSELoss however it seems to be a bug in the version of pytorch, so I can't use it. You can take a look at my code below:

```py
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# We load the training data 
Samples, Ocupancy = common.load_samples()
for i in range(0,Ocupancy.shape[0]):
    if Ocupancy[i] > 1 or Ocupancy[i] < 0:
        print("upsie")

max = np.amax(Samples)
min = np.amin(Samples)

x_test = torch.from_numpy(Samples.astype(np.float32)).to(device)
y_test = torch.from_numpy(Ocupancy.astype(np.float32)).to(device)

train_data = CustomDataset(x_test, y_test)

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size= 22500, shuffle=False) # Batches_size equal to the number of points in each slice 


phi = common.MLP(3, 1).to(device)
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(phi.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
epoch = 10

fit_start_time = time.time()

for epoch in range(epoch):
    for x_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        #optimizer.zero_grad()

        x_train = x_batch.to(device)

        y_train = y_batch.to(device)

        y_pred = phi(x_batch)
        print(y_pred)

        # Compute Loss
        loss = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), y_batch.squeeze())

        print('Epoch {}: train loss: {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))    # Backward pass

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

fit_end_time = time.time()

print("Total time = %f" % (fit_end_time - fit_start_time))
min = -2
max = 2
resolution = 0.05
X,Y,Z  = np.mgrid[min:max:resolution,min:max:resolution,min:max:resolution] # sample way more

xyz = torch.from_numpy(np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel(),Z.ravel()]).transpose().astype(np.float32)).to(device)

eval = LabelData(xyz)

eval_loader = DataLoader(dataset=eval, batch_size= 22500, shuffle=False) # Make bigger batches

# feed the network bit by bit?
i = 0
for x_batch in eval_loader:
    phi.eval()
    labels =  phi(x_batch).to(device)
print(labels)

visualization_iso(X,Y,Z,labels)
```

I expect to the predicted values be 0 or 1, or at least be a probability however it gives me big numbers that I don't understand. Like :19.5953
Please take a look at my code and if you spot any big mistakes please tell me so. I'm really confused since it work quite well before I expanded the size of the data I was using.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but I am trying to answer based on your code in the question.

You are using `BCEwithlogitsloss` which means that the model is expected to output `logits`. `logits` are the output just before using the sigmoid activation. Recall, sigmoid activation is used to convert outputs to probability (essentially to be between 0 and 1). Logits can be any real number.

Based on this, I think you should pass the output of the model through a sigmoid activation i.e. `F.sigmoid(phi(x_batch))`. Or you can also just check if your model's output is greater than 0 or less than 0. If greater than 0, the label should be 1.